# Replicating constructors and new with Object.create()

Tags: javascript, oop

From my limited experience with OOP javascript, a common way to handle multiple objects with different properties but the same methods would be using a constructor as follow:

```
function Animal ( type ) {
    this.type = type
};
Animal.prototype.sayHello = function () {
    return 'Hi, I am a ' + this.type
};
var goat = new Animal( 'Goat' );
```

My understanding here is `goat` would inherit / have a reference to the functions of `Animal`.

I *presume* I can replicate the above with the following object literal notion:

```
var Animal = {
    type : '',
    sayHello : function () {
        return 'Hi, I am a ' + this.type
    }
}
var goat = Object.create( Animal );
goat.type = 'Goat';
```

Is the inheritance to `Animal` lost here, or is `Goat` still referencing `Animal` for methods?

I would like to know if there are any issue using `Object.create()` instead of `new` to replicate a constructor / class. Is there a perf offset or any reason to carry on using `new`?

Any advice would be appreciated, I am happy to add to the question if clarification is needed.

**Updated Object Creation**

```
var Animal = {
    sayHello : function () {
        return 'Hi, I am a ' + this.type
    }
}
var goat = Object.create( Animal, { 'type' : { value: 'goat' } } );
```

Comment: You really want to type `goat.type` (and more) at all call sites? Also what if you want to change it, it would be harder to refactor. This is just hideous. In before someone says "create a factory" in which case you are just doing glorified constructor+prototype.

Comment: @Esailija I added an update on how I would populate `type`. I would be interested to see how you would approach this.

Comment: That's even worse than what I just criticized :D It is still at call sites, external to the object, and even more verbose

Comment: @Esailija can you clarify why, not just for my own understanding, but for other users? I need to create multiple objects. The only difference between all of them is `type`. In the answer below, does `function CreateAnimal(type)` sit better with you? I would appreciate any further comments. Thanks

Comment: Well what is the difference between `var a = new Animal(type)` vs `var a = CreateAnimal(type)` ? Both are just as convenient and put property assignments where they belong. However the code is still a bit ugly on the declaration site where you must explicitly create and return an object - when using normal constructors the creation and return statement are implicit -> that's why you only type `this.type = xxx` inside normal constructor but need the return statement and object.create inside the factory.

Comment: @Esailija Now I follow. Thanks for taking the time to clarify, I *think* I get your pointa and will try to implement them shortly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ...a common way to handle multiple objects with different properties but the same methods would be using a constructor...

Yes, the other common way being (as you've seen) `Object.create`.

> My understanding here is `goat` would inherit / have a reference to the functions of `Animal`.

Not quite. In the `new Animal` expression, `goat` gets assigned the object referenced by `Animal.prototype` as its underlying prototype. There is no *direct* connection to `Animal`, just to `Animal.prototype`. (`Animal.prototype` has a reference back to `Animal` via its `constructor` property, in the normal course of things, although that link can get broken if someone assigns a new object to `Animal.prototype`.)

> Is the inheritance to `Animal` lost here, or is `Goat` still referencing `Animal` for methods?

In your non-constructor example, `goat` gets `Animal` as its underlying prototype, so for any property not found on `goat` itself, the JavaScript engine will look at `Animal` to see if *it* has it. In your example, that means that `goat` is using `sayHello` from `Animal`, but not `type`, because `goat` has its own `type`.

The rough equivalent of this:

```
function Animal ( type ) {
    this.type = type
};
Animal.prototype.sayHello = function () {
    return 'Hi, I am a ' + this.type
};
var goat = new Animal( 'Goat' );
```

...using `Object.create` to set the prototype instead looks like this:

```
var animalPrototype = {
    sayHello: function () {
        return 'Hi, I am a ' + this.type
    }
};
function createAnimal(type) {
    var rv = Object.create(animalPrototype);
    rv.type = type;
    return rv;
};
var goat = createAnimal( 'Goat' );
```

---

Re your comment:

> Would there be any issue including `animalPrototype` inside `createAnimal` and then calling `Object.create(this.animalPrototype)`?

If you mean this:

```
function createAnimal(type) {
    var animalPrototype = {                       // Issue #1
        sayHello: function () {
            return 'Hi, I am a ' + this.type
        }
    };
    var rv = Object.create(this.animalPrototype); // Issue #2
    rv.type = type;
    return rv;
};
var goat = createAnimal( 'Goat' );
```

...then yes, there are two issues:

1. You'd create a *new* `animalPrototype` for each call to `createAnimal`, which defeats the purpose, and 2. `this` within the call to `createAnimal` will either be the global object (loose mode) or `undefined` (strict mode), so `this.animalPrototype` probably isn't the expression you want.

You could do this:

```
function createAnimal(type) {
    var rv = Object.create(createAnimal.proto);
    rv.type = type;
    return rv;
};
createAnimal.proto = {
    sayHello: function () {
        return 'Hi, I am a ' + this.type
    }
};
var goat = createAnimal( 'Goat' );
```

Could be confusing for people, of course, since that looks so much like a constructor function.

Comment: +1 Very nice and objective summary of what's happening. OP - In one word __Yes__ , using `Object.create` lets you do prototypical inheritance in JavaScript. It creates a new object whose _prototype_ is the one you specified. (I'm on the 'prefer Object.create for most cases' side by the way)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Thanks! I take a fairly balanced view. If I'm creating something that feels "classy," I use constructors (via my [Lineage script](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/)). But I use `Object.create` all the time where I just need an object that's mostly the same as, but slightly different from, another specific object. I have a project where we do that a lot, and while it *could* be done with constructor functions, it would be incredibly clunky. I find both of them hugely useful tools. I love how flexible JavaScript is.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you so much for the answer, its cleared up a few questions I had. I updated my question removing preference, so you may need to update the opening to your answer. Again thank you!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder again thank you. Would there be any issue including `animalPrototype` inside `createAnimal` and then calling `Object.create(this.animalPrototype)`? Just for organisation? Maybe a stupid idea.

Comment: @mikedidthis: See the further update at the end of the answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder again, many thanks I appreciate the time taken to address my extra (maybe silly) questions.

Comment: @mikedidthis: No worries! I didn't see any silly questions, FWIW. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Always good to hear, as I am pretty new to JS. I don't suppose you could chime in on this: https://gist.github.com/mikedidthis/6366607 (I am happy to post it as a new question if needed).